# How to render html from angular source code for SEO purpose

Tags: javascript, html, angular, seo

Our web application is built on Angular JS front-end and node js backend.
Each of our pages is dynamic. So whenever I see view source the code looks like

https://prnt.sc/Tuw-HTdKyy37

Due to our business requires the pages to be SEO friendly to rank in google and make google bots crawl our pages. It is only possible if our site source code renders in HTML with proper tags for content such as following:

```
< title > my title </title>
<description> my desc....</description>

<body> my body</body>

etc..
```

Since each web page is built using angular and always renders dynamic content, how can we make it SEO-friendly? So when search engine bots to crawl it has all the tags and content organized as expected by the Google bots for indexing our website

Here is a link to our website for your reference to view the angular code:

https://www.linkscart.com/p/-pressed-powder-shadow/id-643053355d130e55e9d05916

Comment: This is covered by the Angular manual: https://angular.io/guide/universal

Comment: You can use scully too, to generate ssg of your page for better seo friendly angular sites. https://scully.io/

Comment: Did you try SSR? other alternative is to use a prerendering service such as Prerender.io or Rendertron.

Comment: Your question is very broad and it was answered many times [elsewhere](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-universal-meet-the-internet-of-the-future-seo-friendly-single-page-web-apps/). Check it out and come back if you have a specific problem that wasn't solved yet.

Answer (score 2):

Well! let me try helping you out with SSR! Server-side rendering.

- Install Angular Universal: I guess you must be knowing how to install, but let me put the code

  npm install @angular/platform-server @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader ts-loader
- Then create an **angular Universal application**
- Configure the server suitable for angular universal by creating a server file which will be waiting for the incoming requests and render your application on server side. Something like this:

  const express = require('express');
  const { ngExpressEngine } = require('@nguniversal/express-engine');
  const { provideModuleMap } = require('@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader');
  const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main');

  const app = express();

  app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
  provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
  }));

  app.set('view engine', 'html');
  app.set('views', 'dist/browser');

  app.get('*.*', express.static('dist/browser'));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
  });

  app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on http://localhost:3000`);
  });
- Now run `build:ssr`, this will create bundles on either side.
- Last you need to start the server.

THis will work like a charm by rendering your HTML from Angular for SEO purposes.

I found that using this method will help you indexing your web pages which is really important. It was headache to me when I threw myself working on a similar case. Indexing will improve your sites visibility in search engine results.

Comment: I appreciate you put this all together but it's usually better to post a link to a documentation which does a better job of keeping things up to date for users who come to this post later. Your answer is too specific for the broadness of the question and therefore prone to get out of date or to miss important context. And given the broadness of the question, it shouldn't have been answered in the first place.